# How can I get a service to access server data via an $http call?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I make an `$http` call inside a service that is supposed to get data from my server. For some reason I can't get my service to work - nothing happens. I know the server code works because if I place the `$http` call inside a function within my controller, then it gets the server data as expected. Here is the code I have so far:

```
app.service('myService', function($q,$compile,$http) {
    this.getData = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = $http.get('myfile.php').success(function (data) {
            var response = $compile(data)($scope);
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });
        return deferred.promise; 
    };
});
```

Also, I know the code that uses this service works because if I do something like the following,

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    this.getData = function() {
        return 'TEST';
    };
});
```

then I will see the word "TEST" show up in the div that utilizes this service. I feel like I'm very close, but there is something I am missing. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
controller: function($scope, $http, $rootScope, myService){
    var scope = $rootScope;
    scope.viewMyData = function() {
        var element = myService.getData();
        $('#myDiv').html(element);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="viewMyData()">Click Here</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

If I strip the code in `myService` and simply return `TEST` (as above), then I will see "TEST" show up in `id="myDiv"`. But for some reason the `$http` call isn't being triggered.

Comment: Lets see the controller where you call this.

Comment: I added the controller and some more detail. I've been working on it since this was posted and I am still unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@tymeJV is right, but here's my attempt to spell out the example better.  `$http` returns a **promise** interface that allows you to chain callbacks to be executed when the `$http` response returns.  So, in this case, calling `myService.getData()` can't return the result immediately (it's off getting the data from the server), so you need to give it a function to execute *when* the server finally responds.  So, with promises, you simply attach your callback using the `thePromise.then(myCallbackFunc)`.

#### Service

```
app.service('myService', function($q,$compile,$http) {
    this.getData = function() {
        var promise = $http.get('myfile.php');
        promise = promise.then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    };
});
```

#### Controller

```
controller: function($scope, $rootScope, myService){
    var scope = $rootScope;
    scope.viewMyData = function() {
        myService.getData().then(function(data) {
            $('#myDiv').html(element);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around WHY it works. The big question I have now is: where does the ``data`` variable come from (e.g., ``response.data``)? Is ``data`` some kind of global variable accessible to all angular apps?

Comment: `response` is just the argument passed to your promise callback. It's the result of the `$http.get` call which has attributes: `data` for the result of the call, `headers` for the headers returned and `config` for the http parameters (if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.then` in the controller to continue the promise pattern:

```
myService.getData().then(function(data) {
    $('#myDiv').html(data);
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Is there another dependency I need to inject?

Comment: This is right (attach another callback using `then` to the `deferred` returned by `$http.get()`.  I'd guess your issue is all the extra `$compile(data)($scope)` you're doing in the callback.  Btw, `$http.get()` already returns a promise, so you can just chain off that instead of creating your own deferred and resolving it.